# Creating a "dashboard" homescreen in iOS

Tags: android, ios, xcode

I'm creating my first app in iOS and I'm very accustomed to developing in eclipse for Android. My first step is that I need to create a dashboard as the homescreen. I'm a little "confused" as of which layout I should choose in xcode. In android I always select the most basic of settups, and I end up with a blank activity and a blank layout. That's where I would like to start, since that's what I'm used to. I'm wondering if any experienced iOS dev can point me in the right direction into which template to start with.

[image]

It seems really easy to just say to use an empty application, but If I'm going to have to do a lot more settup that is not worth my time, then please enlighten me.

Answer (score 2):

You' probably want to go with a single view application. This will give you a template with a view controller and a blank interface file (your choice of xib or storyboard) that you can build from. From there you can add what ever you want.

Using this template you will immediately be able to build your app to the simulator or to your device. However, if you already have an idea of how you would like your app to work, you could choose tab based if your app should have multiple tabs and most of the work will be done for you, or a utility based app will give you two view controllers, one of which will be presented modally. Etc, etc...